# I can't POST an objectID with postman

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

I'm trying to pass some data with Postman but when I try to POST it an error pops out. The error is the following one (when i try to POST the data):

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\app.js:50:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:463:21)
```

Here is the data I'm trying to pass  (I know for a fact that the issue that is causing this problem is the author value because I've tried deleting it and passing the data and it works correctly.:

```
{
    "title": "This is new message!",
    "content": "So232ic",
    "published": "true",
    "author": "6097ea05631bde908900b5e2"
}
```

This is my controllers and the action I want to perform with this API:

```
exports.create_posts = [


  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) return res.json(errors.array());

    const {title, content, published} = req.body;
    Posts.create({title, content, published, author: req.user._id}, (err, posts) => {
      if(err) return res.json(err);
     posts.populate('author', (err, populatedPost) => {
       res.json(populatedPost);
    })
  })
}
]
```

Here is my models and the database values I have:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  content: {type: String, required: true},
  author: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  published: {type: Boolean, default: true}
}, {timestamps: true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

It is not a database connection problem because the database is correctly connected and the logs show it clearly.

Comment: *"an error pops out"* tells us nothing of value but actual error messages do, along with where the error actually occurs

Comment: okay already dited

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with rendering  a view called "error", seems to be not able to locate the file in

"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Blog Project\app\views"

did you check in mongo if the data arrives in your database seems not a mongo error but a problem with your routes